# Used degree complement I am not sure of

Tags: grammar

中国的发展速度比美国的快得多

I am not quite sure if this is grammatical or not.

I used 快得多 to describe speed of development is faster.

Comment: 得多 degree complement ✓, following predicatively used adjective 快,

submitting 快得多 to online dictionaries supplies many examples, e.g. iciba: 快得多 Much faster 1.

 

在温暖的环境中，咳嗽和喷嚏传播疾病的速度要快得多。

2.

 
向下移动比向上移动快得多.

3.

 
20世纪50年代，美国企业在英国的发展速度要比英国本土企业快得多。(E at iciba)

Comment: Remove的 from  美国“的” 快得多.  In fact, this claim is logically in correct, because USA is already known as developed country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already correct! Some alternatives, you can also use `Adj.+多了` or `Adj.+很多` to express the degree is high. So, all of these sentences have the same meaning.

> 1. 中国的发展速度比美国的**快得多**。
> 2. 中国的发展速度比美国的**快多了**。
> 3. 中国的发展速度比美国的**快很多**。

Comment: So 快多了, 快很多 is also degree complement? I am kind of confused because I thought degree complements have to involve 得。

Comment: @金允雄Oliver Yes, but those degree complements are specifically used for comparison, again to indicate the degree is high. Generally speaking, `A+比+B……+得多/多了/很多` means "A is **much** more……than B". Back to your example, if you just want to say the development rate of 中国 is faster than 美国, you can just omit "得多" - `中国的发展速度比美国的快`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right,but still we could say in other ways, see the change in degree.

1.中国的发展速度比美国的快一点/快一些/快点/快些----a little

2.中国的发展速度比美国的快得很/快很多/快多了/快太多---->=faster